# Importing Module in django

Tags: python, django

#### the module importing in celery.py

```
from celery import Celery
```

#### the module importing in redis.py

```
from redis import StrictRedis
```

## what's my problem?

Django allow the file name the same with the third-party package name.
How the django to import the modules that name is the same with the file name. 
If I do that without django, the program will be broken down and the error  "The module cannot import name Celery was not found" will be raise.

Comment: if you have files named `celery.py` and `redis.py` in your project, they shadow the installed `celery` and `redis` package. Renaming those files (and makeing sure your clear up the cached .pyc files) should solve the issue. Else, please edit your question with enough informatiions to diagnose the issue (a [mcve] would help...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the mistake that I get this error because I run the program with python2.7. It's ok in python3.5.

It isn't a bug about celery or redis.

I think the logic of module importing in python2.7 is different with that in python3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not about wrong file name etc. I think you didn't install library properly or your python path to packages are wrong.

```
pip install celery
```

Run it in your current environment and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I got this mistake since I run the program in python2.7.